# No sacar nada por pantalla

Tags: r

¿Hay alguna forma de que Rstudio no saque ningún mensaje por consola?

Algo en plan `options(max.print=0)` or `message=FALSE`

Quiero hacer un autoejecutable con una barra de progreso. El antivirus me borra un fichero que había creado para ocultar la ventana del cmd, por lo que me interesa que en esta ventana muestre el mínimo código posible cuando ejecute el script. Por estética básicamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La solución dependerá del tipo de salida, imagino que no estamos hablando de los `print` específicos, ¿podrías compartir algún ejemplo de comando y salida?

Comment: Añado captura. Mientras se rellena la barra de progreso de fondo se van cargando las librerías, sale algún que otro warning avisando que algunos directorios ya están creados etc. Queda un poco feo. Y viendo que no puedo ocultar la pantalla me gustaría que estuviera lo más limpia posible.

Comment: Perfecto, creo que lo que te respondí resolvería bien los casos, pruebalo y cualquier cosa me dices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independientemente de mi comentario puedo mostrarte como "anular" dos tipos de mensajes clásicos que se usan en todas la funciones: los prints y los warnings. El escenario sería esto:

```
str(mtcars);warning("Un Warning")
```

Los dos tipos de "mensajes" necesitan un enfoque distinto, en el caso del `print` o salida estándar, hay que usar `capture.output()` y en el caso de los warnings, se puede usar `suppressWarnings()`. El truco sería "envolver" el código de tu Script mediante algo así:

```
redirect_messages <- function(f, file = nullfile()){
  express <- substitute(f)
  return(
    capture.output(
      suppressPackageStartupMessages(
        suppressWarnings( 
          eval(express)
        )), file = file
      )
  )
}
```

Y se ejecutaría así:

```
redirect_messages(
  {str(mtcars);warning("testit")}
)
```

Comentarios:

- La redirección puede enviarse también a un archivo
- Otra posibilidad de solución es intentar redirigir directamente la ejecución del script mediante `>`, acá habría que ver de redirigir la salid estándar y la de error
- Ocultar los warning puede ser problemático eventualmente
- La función no suprime los errores, por ejemplo `stop("Esto es un error")`
- La carga de librerías evidentemente muestra las cosas por afuera de un print clásico y un warning, prueba reducir los mensajes mediante `library("paquete", quietly = TRUE)` o en el caso de `tidyverse` podemos usar `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` (acabo de editar la función para agregar esta función a mi respuesta)

Comment: No sé si lo estoy usando bien, pero si hago por ejemplo redirect_messages( datos <-5 }) no me guarda el valor y el script acaba fallando.  Aunque añadiendo suppressWarnings por el script me esta sirviendo.

Comment: Pasa que  lo que ocurre dentro de la función, queda dentro de la función. Deberías ejecutar todo tu Script  dentro de la función que te pasé.  En el ejemplo que me das , `datos` existe solo dentro de la función.

Comment: La idea de hacerlo así es para que tengas que escribir menos, si quieres ejecutar la función por partes y mantener la asignaciones, deberías cambiar por asignaciones  globales `redirect_messages( datos <<-5 })`